# making close button with java script in php

Tags: php, button

For closing a `<div>`, I use `onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none';"` (in HTML) and it works. But in PHP it doesn't work!

> error:
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u381013597/> public_html/index.html on line 311

When I change `'none'` to `"none"` there is no error but the close item doesn't work.
What is the problem?

Comment: Would you paste some code above and below it?

Answer (score 1):

When you print in PHP you have to watch out with strings. You define a string with single or double quotes. If your string contains for example single quotes and you defined the string with a single quote the quote in the string itself will mean end of string, so you have to escape them:

```
echo 'onclick="this.parentNode.style.display=\'none\';"';
```

As you see I used single quotes for printing here, and I escaped every single quote in the string itself with the backslash character: `\`

Otherwise, the string would ended before `none` (because there is a unescaped single quote that means the end of the string) and the parser would except a `;` character that means end of command or a `,` character that marks that there will be other parameters, but you give none of them, it gets `none` instead. Thats why it throws that he get an unexpected `T_STRING`. If you look at your error message, you will see that it says the same as I did, just in a compact way:

> error: Parse error: syntax error, **unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'** in /home/u381013597/> public_html/index.html on line 311

It also says that there is a `Parse error: syntax error` that means you mistyped something, and he also says where does the problem occurs.

Error messages are your friends, they give a hint about the problem. Read (or at least search for) them and you will be able to develop much faster.